# react - Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I have an array

```
const reportOptions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Report',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Report 2',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Report 3',
  },
]
```

I try to create a new state like below

```
  const [isReportsDownloading, setIsReportsDownloading] = useState(
    reportOptions.map(opt => {
      return { ...opt, isDownloading: false }
    })
  )
```

It gives me this error

```
Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; parenthesize the returned value and move it immediately after the `=>`
```

How to fix?

Comment: That is not an error. It is just an opinion. And in my experienced (not at all humble) opinion, that opinion is wrong. You should not parenthesize the return value of an object literal - that's much harder to read. You should keep your code as is because it is correct and the advice given by the error/warning is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error mean this, although your original code seems valid already, maybe just a eslint error.

```html
  const [isReportsDownloading, setIsReportsDownloading] = useState(
    reportOptions.map((opt) => ({ ...opt, isDownloading: false }))
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Babel Extension]

Remove the above extension from VS Code Editor error will be resolved